# Primefaces application stops working when click button

Tags: primefaces, glassfish-3

Hello please help with the following problem
At times the network is slow and my application programmed in java with primefaces 6.0 and glassfish 3.1 stops working

When I open the page it is shown and the values of the components are load a few seconds late, when clicking on a button when the values of the whole page are not loaded, an error is presented and the application stops working.

Example:

1)The screen is presented and the values of the p: selectOneMenu are not loaded
 [image]

2)When clicking on the first button, shows the following error:

Javascript error:

Error de lectura XML: sección CDATA no cerrada Ubicación: http://localhost:8080/....pag1.xhtml Número de línea 2, columna 43: ....pag1.xhtml:2:43
Error de lectura XML: sección CDATA no cerrada Ubicación: http://localhost:8080/....pag1 Número de línea 2, columna 43: ....pag1.xhtml:2:43
TypeError: PF(...) is undefined

Java error:

Grave: JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException durante el procesamiento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=java.lang.NullPointerException
Grave: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:303)

3)Seconds later load the values of p: selectOneMenu but the application stopped working due to the previous error.
[image]

Now if I open the screen and wait until the values of p: selectOneMenu are loaded, the screen works correctly

How can i fix this

Comment: Press F12 and check your javascript console for errors

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast: thanks for trying to help out but that info is already in the question

Comment: @Kukeltje umm I can't see the images hehe, when I was migrating PF from 3.5 to 7.0 I had that error on one of my application screens, the error in my case was happening because a variable which is called on postconstruct was being null sometimes, and this variable was used on the xhtml so to solve this I had to validate if it was null initialize it, maybe he has something similar also the stacktrace has a nullpointer exception so maybe..

Comment: How many values do you have in the list? Amd always try the latest version in a [mcve]